# PowerPoint VSTO Add-In COM Reference Counting

Tags: memory-leaks, com, vsto, powerpoint, office-addins

We observe ever-increasing memory usage with PowerPoint 2013 (and 2016) as decks are opened and closed without any add-ins. Drivers may include memory fragmentation, undo stack, etc. This observed dynamic makes it tough to be sure that a custom VSTO-based PowerPoint Add-In is not holding on to any underlying COM references.

Is there any way to obtain a reliable count of the underlying COM objects used by a VSTO-based PowerPoint Add-In at a given point in time? Or is there a suitable proxy we should instead be looking for?

The goal of this is to "prove" that the Add-In is not "leaking" any memory above and beyond what is observed without the add-in. Recording e.g. private bytes allocated in these two cases is insufficient because the mere presence of an Add-In changes the memory usage pattern considerably.

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143405/how-to-check-for-memory-leak-for-vsto-outlook-add-in) seems to be a very similar question. Not super-encouraging as it has no answers....

Comment: I think a good memory profiler will be able to show you the COM objects. I believe redgate is able to do that. Are you sure your add-in does not keep references to event handlers when opening new windows etc.? I would start by that because it is very easy to shot a bullet in your foot with that. Actually you should not have to go at COM object levels to inspect those "leaks" because the .NET interop object wrappers will also not be released, so any .NET memory profiler can help you detect those leaks.

Comment: @Benoit, thank you for replying. Yes, we are sure that we are not keeping any references to event handlers hanging around. This effect can be repro'd without any handlers or windows at all.

Comment: My thanks to everyone who took the time to read this. Still interested in ideas if you have one.